# Memory Leak using TIDNotify , threadsafe VCL interaction

Tags: delphi, memory, memory-leaks, indy

the following code is used to allow threadsafe VCL interaction from INDY 10 tcpserver.onexecute();

```
///  a function to write information into a TBitmap 
TVclNavigationImage= procedure( ll, ur, ll_v , ur_v : TPoint ) of object;

TVCLUpdateNotify = class(TIdNotify)
 protected
 f_ll, f_ur, f_ll_v , f_ur_v  : TPoint;
 FProc: TVclNavigationImage;
 procedure DoNotify; override;
 public
 constructor Create(ll, ur, ll_v , ur_v : TPoint; aProc:TVclNavigationImage); reintroduce;
 class procedure UpdateNavigationWindow(ll, ur, ll_v , ur_v : TPoint ; aProc: TVclNavigationImage);
 end;

 class procedure TVCLUpdateNotify.UpdateNavigationWindow(ll, ur, ll_v , ur_v : TPoint ; aProc: TVclNavigationImage);
 begin
 with Create(ll, ur, ll_v , ur_v, aProc) do
     begin
     Notify;
     end;
end;
```

in the Onexecute function there is

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
    ....
    TVCLUpdateNotify.UpdateNavigationWindow(....)
    ....
 end;
```

According to MADSHI debugger this line of code in the serveronexecute() is creating a memory leak. There is no free function inside my class. How to make that code memory leak free ?

Comment: Please fix the title of your question for the sake of everyone's eyes!

Comment: Looks like `TIdNotify` is async. Which means that it's the framework's job to free it. Having had a few websearches, there do seem to have been some Indy versions that had `TIdNotify` bugs that lead to memory leaks. But I'm not very sure about that and know nothing about Indy. Anyway, perhaps you are on an older version of Indy that simply leaks. For example: http://indy.codeplex.com/workitem/22030

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using an up-to-date version of Indy 10.  In older versions, `TIdNotify` did have a memory leak, but that was fixed 10 months ago.

Comment: I made now an update to DELPHGI XE2 Sevicepack 4. The bug is still existing. If I remove the free I suffer memory leaks with the free I get random / frequent access violations because the Free is executed before my painting routine is finished

Comment: The version of Indy 10 that ships with the IDE is not the latest version that is available. Due to interface changes made in Indy over time, Embarcadero cannot include newer Indy releases in IDE Updates, only major releases. I would suggest making a local copy of IdSync.pas, change its unit name and class names, and then add it to your project.  You can then patch it with the latest code from Indy's SVN that contains the memory leak fix.

Comment: `TIdNotify` is asynchronous, you cannot manually call `Free()` on it. You have to let it execute normally and call `Free()` on itself when it is finished. If you switch to `TIdSync`, you can call `Free()` on it, because it is synchronous instead. But know that synchronous will block the calling thread, and introduce a point of deadlock if you invoke it while the server is shutting down.

Comment: I#m in trouble while downloading from https://svn.atozed.com:444/svn/Indy10
,  is there an alternative SVN  for INDY 10

Comment: That SVN link works fine for me. Did you read the [Indy Via SVN](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Download/svn.aspx) instructions?

Comment: Or the [Download](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Download/DevSnapshot.aspx) instructions?

Comment: follow that tutorial:   http://indy.fulgan.com/Getting%20the%20latest%20Indy%2010%20snapshot%20using%20Tortoise%20SVN.pdf , guess there is still some firewall or ... blocking my success

Comment: Just a remark : the org. file ist stored at C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\source\Indy10\Core, I replaced with svn:\Indy10\tags\Indy 10.5.8 - XE2 RTM\Lib\Core file from repository

Comment: between the latest version from IDSYNC on XE2 installation and from the SVN there are just 2 line different , include statements for UNIX operation. still sufferinmg this memory leak with IDSYNC

Comment: Simply replacing the .pas file is not enough. You would have to recompile Indy in order for it to take effect. And the fix for the memory leak required a unit interface change, so it is not enough to just recompile IdSync.pas by itself.

Comment: I assure you, between XE2 and the latest SVN snapshot, there are more than just 2 lines changed in IdSync.pas. The fix required adding an IFDEF'ed `InternalDoNotify()` method to `TIdNotify`.

Comment: OK, will follow your advise within the next days