# What's the difference between TIdNotify and TIdSync?

Tags: delphi, indy10

I'm in trouble understanding the real difference between IDSYNC and IDNOTIFY, what means synchronous / asynchronous
in respect to the lines of code I write ?

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
    ....
    DoSomeThing (TIDNotify)    ....

    DoSomethingOther(TIDsync) ......

 end;
```

Why can't I be sure that both lines of code are executed within the TCPServer Execute function?
Is there only the risk that a few lines of code are not executed within my TIDSynfunction or how can a Deadloack be explained ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you think you need Notify or Sync?

Comment: this question is derived from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13502748/memory-leak-using-tidnotify-threadsafe-vcl-interaction. Can I use any async. function with only GUI output without any risk of a deadlock

Comment: As you look confused by the multithreading terms I advise you to invest some time reading about it. A very good starting point is [Multithreading - The Delphi Way](http://thaddy.co.uk/threads/) by Martin Harvey. After that you'll get the idea about Synchronization and deadlocks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TIdSync and TIdNotify accomplish the same goal - to execute a piece of code in the context of the main thread - but they do it in different ways.

`TIdSync` is synchronous.  The `TIdSync.Synchronize()` method blocks the calling thread until after the main thread has called the `TIdSync.DoSynchronize()` method and it has exited.  A deadlock can occur if `TIdSync.Synchronize()` is called within a server event handler while the main thread is shutting down that server.  This is because the main thread is blocked waiting for the server to terminate its threads. But the thread is blocked waiting for the main thread to process the sync request.

`TIdNotify` is asynchronous.  The `TIdNotify.Notify()` method adds the `TIdNotify.DoNotify()` method into a background queue and exits immediately, so the calling thread is not blocked.  The main thread calls the `TIdNotify.DoNotify()` method at its leisure.  There is no deadlock in this situation.