# TIdSync synchronizes incorrectly

Tags: delphi, synchronization, indy, indy10

I have a problem that when I synchronize TIdSync in Delphi 7 (with latest Indy) inside multiple threads at the same time, it executes the same TIdSync instance multiple times.
Here is a simple code. TIdSync is created and called inside my TThread. It should pass and show its handle for this case. But I get a list with same handles in the memo. It works correctly in Delphi 2010+ (probably because it supports anonymous methods).

I am not sure if I understand how TIdSync should work, use it wrong, or there is a bug or some race condition?

```
type
  TMySync = class(TIdSync)
  protected
    procedure DoSynchronize; override;
  public
    FID: Integer;
  end;

type
  TTestThread = class(TThread)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

procedure TTestThread.Execute;
var
  sync: TMySync;
begin
  // synchronize some data
  sync:=TMySync.Create;
  try
    sync.FID:=Integer(sync); // this handle
    sync.Synchronize;
  finally
    sync.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TMySync.DoSynchronize;
begin
  // show handle and stored handle
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(Integer(Self))+' : '+IntToStr(FID));
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  // execute multiple threads
  for i:=0 to 10 do
    with TTestThread.Create(True) do
      Resume;
end;
```

I get list like this in Delph 7 with same hadnles (so it does not pass right values)
38972948 : 38972948
38970260 : 38970260
38970260 : 38970260
38970260 : 38970260
...

and in Delphi 2010 it is correct
39063248 : 39063248
39063296 : 39063296
39063312 : 39063312
39063328 : 39063328

It is quite unpleasant problem as you see. Any hint appreciated.

Comment: `TTestThread` must have `FreeOnTerminate` set to true to avoid leaking thread objects. `Resume` is unsafe to use (and deprecated since Delphi-XE).

Comment: I cannot see any misbehaviour. What makes you feel so? Although if there would be a problem your code is not the best to show that problem. In fact you see here the different behaviour from the memory manager D7 vs. D2010 :o)

Comment: @LURD: True, FreeOnTerminate should be there but does not cause the problem. Just a test case. Resume is correct - it is Delphi 7.

Comment: @SirRufo: This code includes whole code which produces the problem in Delphi 7 so there has to be something. The only explanation would be that there is some race condition in TIdSync but hard to believe that it is there for 10 years and nobody noticed.

Comment: Do you know that a memory address can be reused once it is freed? That is what you see: reused memory adress. Did you debug your code and track create/destroy of TIdSync?

Comment: Delphi memory manager is fast on single thread but slow on multithread and sometimes you have some kind of "synchronisation" on simple create/destroy inside a thread. D2010 is somwhow better on this than D7. That is what your code shows to me, nothing more

Comment: Instead of the pointer ID, use a guid. `CreateGuid(sync.FID);` Note, apply error checking.

Comment: I use FastMM in D7, so memory manager is not the issue. Yes, memory can be reused but I don't understand how that would happen. It is freed after it is synchronized. Even when I don't free the object and memory should not be reused, it still behaves the same.

Comment: The real thread start and the creating of TMySync is **not** done for all at the same time. Each thread will start at any time you do not control. So one thread can destory the TMySync and another is creating a TMySync

Comment: @smooty86, reuse of a pointer could happen. If you use a guid instead, you can prove that the objects are unique.

Comment: @LURD but only if CreateGUID returns a unique GUID ;o)

Comment: Yes, but it should not reuse memory if I don't free the object. I still get same values from it. I also tried with GUID, again same result.

Comment: When I use classic way - Synchronize(sync.DoSynchronize) it works correctly. TIdSync uses internally one thread (GNotifyThread). All object use this to synchronize. When I create own thread - TMySync.Create(TIdThread.Create(True)) it works also correctly. I suspect the problem is somewhere there.

Comment: Have you tried [TIdNotify](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13536901/576719)?

Comment: I can't use TIdNotify. But I think I can confirm that it is a race condition bug (?) in TIdSync. All threads call same Synchronize of the same thread which shares same variable FSynchronize which is then synchronized. I have to report it. Maybe @Remy-Lebeau will know.

Comment: @smooty86: look again more carefully at the implementation of `TIdSync`. It is just a thin wrapper for `TThread.Synchronize()`, and in Delphi versions that provide a **static** version of `TThread.Synchronize()` (which includes Delphi 7), that static method is used, passing in a nil `TThread` pointer. The global `GNotifyThread` object is not used, and thus there is no race condition on any `FSynchronize` variable. In fact, in those Delphi versions, `TIdSync` is marked as `deprecated` anyway,you should just use `TThread.Synchronize()` directly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I did not realize I can use that directly. That works flawlessly.

Comment: @smooty86: Your analysis of the `FSynchronize` race condition is correct when using the non-static version of `TThread.Synchronize()`. I hadn't noticed that before. The non-static version is not designed to be used across thread boundaries, it should only be called within the `Execute()` method of the `TThread` it is being called on. I may have to redesign `TIdNotifyThread` to account for that in old Delphi versions. You can also use the `TIdSync` constructor that takes a `TIdThread` as input so you can specify which thread object `Synchronize()` gets called on.

Comment: @smooty86: I filed a bug report with QualityPortal: [RSP-15139: Race condition in TThread.Synchronize](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15139).

Answer (score 1):

Please check again with a small change to lock out the reuse of memory addresses:

```
type
  TTestThread = class( TThread )
  private
    sync: TMySync;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

{ TTestThread }

destructor TTestThread.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
  sync.Free;
end;

procedure TTestThread.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
  sync    := TMySync.Create;
  sync.Id := Integer( sync );
  sync.Synchronize;
end;
```

As you will see, there is no problem at all

Comment: It works the same. Did you test it in D7 and it worked correctly?

Comment: I tried both with FreeOnTerminate and without freeing.

Comment: No I did not test with D7, but if there is a problem, then it is a problem of the memory manger and not of TIdSync

Comment: If you free the thread, then you also free the TMySync and the memory can be reused